# Activity playing at Status Bar Notification bar when Home Pressed

Tags: android

I am program Music Play in WebView getting link from my website.

I want my WebView activity kept with Status Bar Notification when user pressed Home Button. Please help give me some way.

## My Code in WebView:

```
public class playlist extends Activity {
private WebView mWebView;
MediaPlayer myMediaPlayer;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.playlist);

    mWebView = new WebView(this);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.playlist);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.mp3skull.com/justin_bieber.html");
}

public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient  
{  
    @Override  
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {  
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);  
    }  
    @Override  
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {  
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        view.loadUrl(url);  
        return true;
    }  
}
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        mWebView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
@Override
public void onPause() {
    mWebView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mWebView.destroy();
    super.onPause();
}
}
```

This code when user press Home Button the Music also stop because of Voide onPause(), but I need keep music playing on Status Bar Notification with correct activity. Please help me.

Regards,
Virak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [onUserLeaveHint ()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) method for playing sound when user press Home Key as doc says:

> Called as part of the activity lifecycle when an activity is about to
>   go into the background as the result of user choice. For example, when
>   the user presses the Home key, onUserLeaveHint() will be called, but
>   when an incoming phone call causes the in-call Activity to be
>   automatically brought to the foreground, onUserLeaveHint() will not be
>   called on the activity being interrupted. In cases when it is invoked,
>   this method is called right before the activity's onPause() callback.

For playing sound on Home key press use [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html). start it in *onUserLeaveHint()*
of your Activity and this service auto stop when job is finished.as:

```
public class MyService extends IntentService {

public MyService(String name) {
    super(name);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
public MyService () {
  super("MyService");
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         // PLAY SOUND HERE
    }
}
```